# How do I access the session object in a Rails performance test?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am writing some performance tests and I want the user to be logged 
in:

```
class CompaniesTest < ActionController::PerformanceTest 
  fixtures :all 
  def setup 
    login_as(:cyrille) 
  end 
  def test_homepage 
    get '/' 
  end 
end
```

The problem is: how should I implement login_as?

I tried:

```
  private 
  def login_as(user) 
    @request    = ActionController::TestRequest.new 
    @request.session[:user] = user ? users(user).id : nil 
  end
```

But the session[:user] is empty when it gets checked by the 
application.

Obviously there must be a session object created by the 
PerformanceTest, but I can't see how I am supposed to access it.

Answer (score 0):

I would try removing this line:

```
@request = ActionController::TestRequest.new
```

`PerformanceTest` is a subclass of `IntegrationTest` so `@request` should already be defined.